# How to hide Swagger OpenAPI operation with path parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, openapi

Swagger creates two endpoints for me

`/Document/GetDocument/`

and

`/Document/GetDocument/{documentId}`

But they're the exact same endpoint, same parameters, same description.

The only difference is that the built-in tester creates a URL like this `/Document/GetDocument/abc123` vs `/Document/GetDocument?documentId=abc123`.  A problem I ha with the first one is it doesn't seem to take any special characters like `.`, `@`, `!` properly to my API.

Comment: posting controller code for the 1 (or 2 ??) endpoint method(s) might help.

Comment: special characters need to be url encoded, if they are a query parameter (1st instance) or path parameter(2nd instance). the reason you have two endpoints is they are meant to be resource driven. You _should_ have individual resource operations on the 2nd one, such as PUT, DELETE, GET. the first one should either create (POST) a new document to the collection or (GET) return a collection of documents. 

it's recommended not to use http verbs in your uri  `/Document/GetDocument` should be `/documents`
to be "restful", the uris you should have are:  `/documents` and `/documents/{documentId}`